USB hub port control always low
I'm using USB5744 as the hub controller with an external power switch. Port 1 and Port 2 are enabled but Prt_Ctl1 and Prt_Ctl2 are always low. I'm not sure how the logic high can be generated with open drain on both the hub and the power switch. Do you need to configure the hub? If so, how?


Please show the circuit schematic for your controller and power switch.

All necessary information should be given in the datasheet and application notes and in reference designs. Please read them.

Are you connecting your hub to a host computer, or just checking voltages in stand-alone mode?

The power switch is connected the same way as the datasheet and the development board. I've read all the application notes and the datasheet. Now we're able to pull the enable pins high with software configuration. But I don't understand with open drain output on both the power switch and the hub port ctrl, how is the pin pulled high without any voltage rail connected to the internal pull up resistor?

You did not answer the question, "Are you connecting your hub to a host computer," or not?
